# requestAnimationFrame is not triggering the function supplied to it

Tags: javascript, html, requestanimationframe

I implemented a infinite loop animation using setInterval. I now like to change the implementation to requestAnimationFrame() so that I will have performance which I am after. For some reasons, requestAnimationFrame() does not call the function supplied to it.

My code looks like this;

```js
var index = 0;
var $btn = $('.btn');
function btnBlinkRun() {
  if (index < 2) {
    index = index + 1;
  } else {
    index = 0;
  }
  $('#ani--scaleinout').removeAttr('id');
  $($btn[index]).attr('id', 'ani--scaleinout');
  window.requestAnimationFrame(btnBlinkRun);
}

btnBlinkRun();
```

```css
.btn{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#ani--scaleinout {
  animation: zoominout 1s ease-in;
}

@keyframes zoominout {
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  
  <div class="btn" id="ani--scaleinout"></div>
    <div class="btn"></div>

    <div class="btn"></div>

  
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post code that doesn't error?

Comment: @gforce301 updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It executes alright. But it does not do what you want it to, i presume.
Animation frame fires on every single rending frame (e.g. 60fps) and not on CSS animation keyframes.

The `animationend` event is your friend here.

```js
var index = 0;
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
function btnBlinkRun() {
  if (index < 2) {
    index = index + 1;
  } else {
    index = 0;
  }
  const element = document.querySelector('#ani--scaleinout');
  element.id = null;
  buttons[index].id = 'ani--scaleinout';
  buttons[index].addEventListener("animationend", btnBlinkRun, { once: true });
}

btnBlinkRun();
```

```css
.btn{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#ani--scaleinout {
  animation: zoominout 1s ease-in;
}

@keyframes zoominout {
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="btn" id="ani--scaleinout"></div>
  <div class="btn"></div>
  <div class="btn"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So how can I avoid using setInterval function at all and use something more lightweight?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve here. Maybe you can make it work with CSS only.

Comment: Unfortunately, CSS does not support running one animation after other animation in a loop sequentially.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there any ways that I can add delay before blinkRun called?

Comment: Sure, just use `setTimeout` in the event handler, e.g. `() => setTimeout(btnBlinkRun, 1000)` instead of just `btnBlinkRun`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what's going on is you are firing `requestAnimationFrame` multiple times per second.  Your css animation has a duration of `1s`.  But you are removing the attribute every x ms.

It is triggering, it's just happening so fast you can't see it. To demonstrate change your call to `window.requestAnimationFrame` to use a setTimeout and you'll notice the animation:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(btnBlinkRun);
}, 1000);
```

Not saying this is a preferred solution, but explaining why this is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am looking for running the animation continuously and sequentially. setTimeout executes just once.

Comment: No, it runs continuously due to btnBlinkRun calling itself again and again.  I do like the above answer though.  Good information @forethought